# How to smoothly stretch div with position absolute?

Tags: html, css, sass

I can't smoothly stretch left-top div to 100vh height and 100vw width. 
Box .btn smoothly going as I wanted, but whole background (div .red) has some kind of lag and goes smoothly only in the end.
Any tips, please? :)

```css
@keyframes stretchIn {
  0% {
    height: 50vh;
    width: 50vw;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}

body {
  background: #999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body .red,
body .blue,
body .green,
body .yellow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
}

body .red {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #a04951;
  transition: 1s;
}

body .red:hover {
  animation: stretchIn 5s both;
}

body .red .btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  top: 45%;
  left: 45%;
}

body .blue {
  background: #c06c84;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

body .green {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #6c5b7b;
}

body .yellow {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #355c7d;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <div class="btn"></div>
</div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jagus00/pen/VwwzNYw)

Comment: please post a minimal reproducible example here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm starting `z-index` with hover instead of starting with animation.

```css
@keyframes stretchIn {
  to {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
  }
}

body {
  background: #999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.red,
.blue,
.green,
.yellow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
}

.red {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #a04951;
}

.red:hover {
  animation: stretchIn 5s both;
  z-index: 1;
}

.red .btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  top: 45%;
  left: 45%;
}

.blue {
  background: #c06c84;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.green {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #6c5b7b;
}

.yellow {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #355c7d;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <div class="btn"></div>
</div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@dgknca is right in a sense of putting your red div to the front. Your div is not lagging, it just starts to stretch **behind** other divs (note, it comes first in the order, hence is "covered" by elements that come after it). You can either use z-index or change the order of the elements:

```css
@keyframes stretchIn {
  0% {
    height: 50vh;
    width: 50vw;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}

body {
  background: #999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body .red,
body .blue,
body .green,
body .yellow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
}

body .red {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #a04951;
  transition: 1s;
}

body .red:hover {
  animation: stretchIn 5s both;
}

body .red .btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  top: 45%;
  left: 45%;
}

body .blue {
  background: #c06c84;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

body .green {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #6c5b7b;
}

body .yellow {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #355c7d;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
<div class="red">
  <div class="btn"></div>
</div>
```